# Cakephp change the Form->input output

Tags: php, forms, cakephp

I am trying to achieve the output where I have a wrapper div which contains a label and an inner div, and within the inner div I have the form input.

My output should look like this:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label>Name:</label>
  <div class="form-input">
    <input type="text" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is my current form object in php:

```
echo $this->Form->input('name', array(
    'class' => 'form-input',
    'div' => 'form-group',
    'label' => array('class' => 'control-label')));
```

But this adds the class form-input to the actual input itself.
How would I be able to achieve this while still keeping true to the CakePHP way of doing things?

TIA!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use input options 'before', 'after', 'between' http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html#options   I haven't verified it, but I think it should look something like this:

```
echo $this->Form->input('name', array(
    'between' => '<div class="form-input">',
    'after' => '</div>',
    'div' => 'form-group',
    'label' => array('class' => 'control-label')));
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

```
echo $this->Form->input('name', array(
 'div' => 'form-group',
 'before' => '<div class="form-input">',
 'after' => '</div>',
 'label' => array('class'=>'control-label')
));
```

I think this works.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, however I had to use "between" instead of before